# BASH count with two digit even its a one digit task

Tags: bash

i'am currently trying to count +1 to a variable which could contain either

```
02
15
```

i use the following line to count one up, but the output seems not to be two digit. So if 02 is the $version and count one up, it will give the output "3" and not "03". Sure if its already two digit, it works.

```
$((echo $version) + 01))
```

how can I get bash to count with two digits and output it correctly?

Comment: You don't. Computer don't count with digits (nor base, ...). Number are numbers. It is only when inputing or printing them that they need to choose a human representation. Bash is the closest thing to a contradiction to that rule (since there aren't really numbers, just strings, including strings that are decimal representation of numbers). And yet, even in bash, it is not when computing things that you choose the number of digits. It is when printing things. So, just `((version += 1))`. And when you need to have a 2 digits representation of that, use, for example `$(printf "%02d" $version)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf` to format a number. Also, note that `08` fails in numeric expressions, as numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
for n in 02 08 15 001; do 
    i=${n##+(0)}  # Remove leading zeros. Needs the extglob.
    length=${#n}
    printf "%0${length}d\\n" $((i + 1))
done
```

Comment: You beat me with 18 seconds :-)

Comment: I'm beat with an hour :-)